# (simple) Jquery ajax not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The alert box will display nothing, and not return any data from any URL when it should be showing the google page!  Any ideas?  I'm using POST because I'm trying to get it to send querystring data as well.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: cross-domain-policy.. search for it here at SO... or try google about that topic...

Comment: Good point Reigel. I made the assumption that Google was put in as an arbitrary example.

Comment: Thanks!  I assumed ajax should be able to request a page from any server, seems a bit strange to me why this is not possible, so now I'm making it request to my server and then my server will request the external page.

Comment: you can read it here...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy it's for security reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yea TOm,

You are doing cross-domain scripting.

change the URL to a file which is in your own Domain.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "anyfileinYourDomain.xxx",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont think, changing the domain makes any difference, as URL is suppose to link to a file.

Comment: Actually he is doing cross-domain access. There are different technique to do cross-domain Ajax.

Comment: @Starx - not really... you're still bound with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if you own google.com which I believe is at least unlikely:) (cross domain issues)

To overcome this you can make post to your server and let server connect to google.com, then you can respond to the user with data retrieved from google.com.

Comment: @Lukasz_Dziedzia how to do that?

Comment: In a few words you need to write server side script that communicate with google and exposes data

Answer (score -2):

I would try setting the dataType to html and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow!! So much hate out there. Can you please retract the down votes. Check the documentation for the ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here is the brief info from the jquery documentation:

dataType
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)

The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. 

Not sure why that doesn't make sense? Please explain?

Comment: Just because I commented doesn't mean I necesserially down voted you, also no one is hating you.  Every comment is appreciated.  The reason I wrote it doesn't make sense is because I am attempting to retrieve the google homepage, which will return HTML anyway.  With ajax requests I have never seen it necessary or possible (but I might be wrong) to specify the return type, I always treat returned data as text.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily saying that you down voted me. I just hating because it was two down votes right away when that is a valid possibility. But I just meant in general whoever down voted. Most people don't use because it does make an intelligent guess as to the contents. But sometimes it can be wrong in which case it is good to force the dataType so there is no confusion.

I did misunderstand your post in that I just assumed that the google request was an arbitrary entry as to hide your internal page request. The cross domain comments have already been made so no need to mention again.